# Why is my Java gui resizing labels?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to make a Java interface using Netbeans, and I'm having a problem that the interface looks different when the program runs than when I am building it in Netbeans.

More specifically, It looks like there is some kind of unwanted padding being added around my labels. In the image below, the right side shows the Netbeans look, and on the left the application is running.

Why is there this difference and how can I get rid of it? Thanks!

[image: java problem]

[edit]
I looked through the generated code and found this

```
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jLabel4)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
```

I am guessing this line is adding it:

```
.addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
```

The problem is that Netbeans doesn't let you modify the generated code.

Comment: It would be helpful for you to post some code, not just the visual effect, though that explains a lot. Lack of code is probably why your question was voted down.

Comment: Like I said, I am using the Netbeans GUI editor, so the code is hidden.

Comment: @Adam - it *generates* code, and it's in your project Otherwise it wouldn't do anything.

Comment: Perhaps it's time to start learning to hand-code Swing, I think.

Comment: I know you guys are all pros that do hand coding, but for a little side project for some of us it is not worth the time to learn the hand coding. Hence, why experienced programmers created tools like this. If nobody knows why the space is being added, I can live with it. I was just hoping to make it look nicer and maybe there was some quick and simple fix to it that only required changing a single property. Thanks for trying though!

Comment: Sorry. I missed the fact that code is encapsulated in a library you cannot see. There should be a way to control the labels, but alas, I'm not a GUI expert. BTW, I've been programming for pay since '85, and I'd be using a library and will be using a Clojure/Swing library. I avoid hand coding. Time doesn't allow it these days.

Comment: One of the problems with using NetBeans code generation is that it defaults to use GroupLayout to place components on a GUI. This results in *almost* a WSIWYG form editor, but not quite, and not only is this layout very difficult for humans to read and understand, if you edit the layout by hand, you break the code generation contract making your GUI non-editable by the IDE's form editor. Because of this and for many other reasons I strongly advise even newbies like you to bite the bullet and code things by hand.

Comment: @Hovervraft Alternately, the OP could learn to use the GUI designer properly. NetBeans and GroupLayout are *very* powerful and let you make high-quality resizeable layouts, but it's definitely not a trivial task. For someone new to Swing, handcoding with nested Border- / Box- / Flow layouts might well be easier. (The advantage of GroupLayout is that it can eliminate nesting containers and layouts, and it might be easier to put new components and align them with everything you want than when using GridBagLayout.)

Comment: @Adam, learning to hard code swing layout is for sure useful but for the real, bigger than 'hello world' project would be silly, use NB designer, its really good but sometimes you would bump on smth like this and it will take time for you to come up with your way of using it. I will recommend you to post your project/part of it, on the github or somewhere where people can download it and see for themselves what have you done there.

Answer (score 2):

Adam, the resizing is usually handled by the [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html). SO make sure you are using the correct [LayoutManger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [`GroupLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html) expands the form elements to fit the panel. In the image on the right, the panel containing the form components is wider. The layout has adjusted the form to better fill the panel. The section on [*Component Size and Resizability*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html) offers some guidance.